# Save image with different channels OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to save this image[image]

using this code:

```
def get_inputs(filename, pred_folder, truth_folder=None, extend_mask_folder=None):
    fid = filename.split(".")[0]
    inputs = []
    pred = cv2.imread(path.join(pred_folder, filename), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    pred_msk = pred / 255.
    pred_msk = pred_msk[..., 0] * (1 - pred_msk[..., 1])
    pred_msk = 1 * (pred_msk > 0.5)
    pred_msk = pred_msk.astype(np.uint8)
    y_pred = measure.label(pred_msk, neighbors=8, background=0)

    props = measure.regionprops(y_pred)
    for i in range(len(props)):
        if props[i].area < 10:
            y_pred[y_pred == i + 1] = 0
    y_pred = measure.label(y_pred, neighbors=8, background=0)
    nucl_msk = (255 - pred[..., 0])
    nucl_msk = nucl_msk.astype('uint8')
    y_pred = watershed(nucl_msk, y_pred, mask=((pred[..., 0] > pixels_threshold)), watershed_line=True)
    to_save = y_pred * 255
    cv2.imwrite(path.join(postprocess_labels, '{0}.tif'.format(fid)), y_pred * 255)
```

but the image comes out like this:
[image]

Does this have anything to do with the default save channels? 
How can I save the exact same picture that I printed by using `imshow()`.

Regards

Comment: the `watershed` function returns a binary image, so what you are saving is exactly right. how are you displaying the image?

Comment: `cv2.imshow("image", image)`

Comment: The saved image does not match the displayed image though

Comment: the output is correct though, what are you trying to do? maybe you don't actually want to use `watershed`? you function doesn't just save the image, it does binarization first